# Javascript to focus on the next input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, primefaces

I can't get this to work, please help. 
I have a table where each TD has an input text field. I want that after the user press one letter, the focus goes to the next input text field in the next TD. My code it's not working... I'm using primefaces:

```
<p:inputText value="#{officialVar.officialAnswer}"
    id="officialAnswer" maxlength="1"
    onblur="value=value.toUpperCase()"
    onkeyup="$(this).next('input').focus();" />
```

I have issued some alerts in the onkeyup and here are the results:

```
alert($(this));
    [object Object]
alert($(this).value);
    undefined
alert($(this).next('input'))
    [object Object]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks

**EDIT**: if I had 2 fields in the same TD, it would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it won't work because all the `<input>` are **not siblings** but their parent `<td>`s are. See the [next() API docs](http://api.jquery.com/next/). When you use `next()` you are referring to the immediate following sibling of the element.

This should work:

```
onkeyup="$(this).parent('td').next('td').find('input').focus();"
```